# Is there any way to check field dependency in salesforce

Tags: metadata-api, field-dependencies

let say i have a field abc__c in account object and i want to check where this field has been used then i can do following things

1) retrieve all org metadata through ant or workbench or eclipse and do a text search in that data - (it is ineffective as it will just search the field name and there can be many field with same name or there can be code commented which will also come in search)

2) delete the field in salesforce org, if there is any dependency of it then the references will come in next page (Effective but more manual work)

Here in this question the thing that i want to find out is that, is there any function in salesforce which is available in metadata Api through which we can get the field dependency that salesforce find out during field deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an upcoming Dependency API that is in pilot for Summer 18. It allows using the Tooling API to extract metadata dependency information.

More information on StackExchange in [pchittum's answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/217009/46017), which includes a link to the TrailheadX presentation.

Andrew Fawcett demoed a really neat graphing tool for showing dependencies built on the API in his [PhillyForce 18](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuj4Vcti-Z4) talk.

So the answer right now is no, but a real, stable solution to this issue is coming, and hopefully we'll see it generally available within the next few releases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parametrized search via workbench: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_search_parameterized.htm. But still it does not provide all metadata information but you can have at least sense of apex and pages references.

So, **as per now**, there is no standard way to achieve that except above explained workarounds by you :(

**UPDATE IN 2024:**

Salesforce has standard way to achieve it for custom fields as below:

- Goto --> Setup --> Object Manager -->  and then go to field
- You can see a button "Where is This Used?"
  [image]